# Saved data from TBlobField is corrupted for lengths >= 100KB

Tags: delphi, blob

I'm modifying a program that is written in Delphi 6.0

I have a table in Oracle with a BLOB column named FILE_CONTENT.

I have already managed to upload an XML File that is about 100 KB. I have verified that the file content was correctly uploaded using SQL Developer.

The problem I have is when I try to download back the file content from DB to a file. This is an example code I'm using to donwload it:

```
procedure TfrmDownload.Save();
var 
  fileStream: TFileStream;
  bField: TBlobField;
begin
  dmDigital.qrGetData.Open;
  dmDigital.RequestLive := True;
  bField := TBlobField(dmDigital.qrGetData.FieldByName('FILE_CONTENT'));
  fileStream := TFileStream.Create('FILE.XML', fmCreate);
  bField.SaveToStream(fileStream);
  FlushFileBuffers(fileStream.Handle);
  fileStream.Free;
  dmDigital.qrGetData.Close;
end;
```

The previous code already downloads the file content to FILE.XML. I'm using `RequestLive:=True` to be able to download a large BLOB (otherwise the file content is truncated to 32K max)

The resulting file is the same size as the original file. However, when I compare the downloaded file with the original one there are some differences (for example the last character is missing and other characters are also changed), therefore it seems to be a problem while downloading the content.

Do you know what cuould be wrong?

The problem seems to be related to Delphi code because I already tried with C# and the file content is downloaded correctly.

Comment: Why are you calling FlushFileBuffers

Comment: I now know that it doesn't make a difference if I call it or not, but at first it seemed that the file was truncated (at least the last characters)... thats why I tried with flushfilebuffers

Comment: It's not a good idea. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TBlobField.SaveToStream()` directly, use `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` instead (which is what `TBlobField.SaveToStream()` uses internally anyway):

```
procedure TfrmDownload.Save;
var 
  fileStream: TFileStream;
  bField: TField;
  bStream: TStream;
begin
  dmDigital.qrGetData.Open;
  try
    dmDigital.RequestLive := True;
    bField := dmDigital.qrGetData.FieldByName('FILE_CONTENT');
    bStream := bField.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(bField, bmRead);
    try
      fileStream := TFileStream.Create('FILE.XML', fmCreate);
      try
        fileStream.CopyFrom(bStream, 0);
        FlushFileBuffers(fileStream.Handle);
      finally
        fileStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      bStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    dmDigital.qrGetData.Close;
  end;
end;
```

`TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` allows the `DataSet` to decide the best way to access the BLOB data.  If the returned `TStream` is not delivering the data correctly, then either the `TStream` class implementation that `CreateBlobStream()` uses is broken, or the underlying DB driver is buggy.  Try taking `CopyFrom()` out of the equation so you can verify the data as it is being retrieved:

```
procedure TfrmDownload.Save;
const
  MaxBufSize = $F000;
var
  Buffer: array of Byte;
  N: Integer;
  fileStream: TFileStream;
  bField: TField;
  bStream: TStream;
begin
  dmDigital.qrGetData.Open;
  try
    dmDigital.RequestLive := True;
    bField := dmDigital.qrGetData.FieldByName('FILE_CONTENT');
    bStream := bField.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(bField, bmRead);
    try
      fileStream := TFileStream.Create('FILE.XML', fmCreate);
      try
        //fileStream.CopyFrom(bStream, 0);
        SetLength(Buffer, MaxBufSize);
        repeat
          N := bStream.Read(PByte(Buffer)^, MaxBufSize);
          if N < 1 then Break;
          // verify data here...
          fileStream.WriteBuffer(PByte(Buffer)^, N);
        until False;
        FlushFileBuffers(fileStream.Handle);
      finally
        fileStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      bStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    dmDigital.qrGetData.Close;
  end;
end;
```